# C warning : enumerated type mixed with another type

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, coverity

I have an enum defined like this -

```
typedef enum 
{
    emp1 = 0u,
    emp2,
    emp3
}employid;
```

C throws me warnings for following operations

**Problem 1:**

```
unsigned int var; // 32 bit in my compiler

typedef struct
{
   employid e;
}mystruct;

mystruct s;
s.e = var; // **getting warning enumerated type mixed with another type**
```

**Problem 2:**

```
somefun(var); // **getting warning enumerated type mixed with another type**

function definition is somefun(employ e);
```

I don't understand that even though my enum values are positive since 1st element is 0u why is C compiler shouting at me for assigning it to a unsigned int?

Comment: Since you have defined e as an employ, you cant assign it to an unsigned int

Comment: There's no guarantee that `var` is one of the enum values in either case.

Comment: @RetiredNinja that's true what can we do to suppress the warning ? I don't want to add range checks

Comment: @RetiredNinja any help ?

Comment: Casting it may help with the warning. It won't make using invalid values any better though.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yup! That helped thanks

Comment: Casting it made the warning go away but it didn't solve the problem. See my answer below. Why exactly do you need to mix unsigned int with enum? You might have a perfectly good reason for this, but if so what is that reason?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine as far as C language rules go. These are just extra diagnostics telling you that the code is fishy.

An `unsigned int` may hold values not matching any valid enumeration constant, in which case you will end up with `s.e` holding an invalid value. That is: most of the time, it doesn't really make any sense to mix plain integers with enums. If you find yourself doing so, the root problem is likely on the program design level.

In case you are sure that `var` holds an ok value, you could do an explicit cast `s.e = (employid)var;`. But more likely, `var` should have been declared as `employid` to begin with.

Comment: Hi , so the problem comes because I am storing my variable which is a part of enum and passing it across multiple function calls. So the s.e=var gives error although the function from where it was passed , had declared it as a part of enum. Strange